(Completed) Site maintenance - Mon, Sept 16 2024, 21:00 UTC to Tue, Sept 17 2024, 2:00 UTC (Mon, Sept 16 2024, 5pm-10pm ET)
[UPDATE - Maintenance has been completed]
We have planned network maintenance that will impact Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange users. The window is scheduled for Monday, September 16 2024, 21:00 UTC to Tuesday, September 17 2024, 2:00 UTC (Monday, September 16 2024, 5pm-10pm ET).
The maintenance involves a database migration. During the maintenance:

Users who are already logged in will remain logged in and have normal
access.
Users who are not already logged in when the maintenance window
begins will be unable to access the site during the window using an
email/password. They will still be able to log in via Google, GitHub,
or Facebook if they have this login method set up.
New users will be unable to register a new account during this time.

I'll update this post when the maintenance has been completed.

Thank you for your practice of informing users well in advance of these events.

and also for giving us some info about what the maintenance is about (you don't need to, but I appreciate it)
